# How can I catch error and prevent tap execution? RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, try-catch

```
    this.web3.useKeystoreAccess(this.passwordCtrl.value)
      .pipe(
        catchError(() => this.router.navigate(['some-route'])),
        tap(() => this.router.navigate(['some-route2']))
      ).subscribe();
```

I would like to prevent tap execution if an error happened.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the catchError() throws an error, the pipeline will continue. You can throw an error something like this:

```
this.web3.useKeystoreAccess(this.passwordCtrl.value)
  .pipe(
    catchError(() => {
         this.router.navigate(['some-route']);
         return throwError('error!')
    }),
    tap(() => this.router.navigate(['some-route2']))
  ).subscribe();
```

Alternatively, you can move the tap *before* the catchError()

```
this.web3.useKeystoreAccess(this.passwordCtrl.value)
  .pipe(
    tap(() => this.router.navigate(['some-route2']))
    catchError(() => this.router.navigate(['some-route'])),
  ).subscribe();
```

Then when the error occurs, it will skip the other operators in the pipeline and jump to the catchError.

Comment: The second option seems counter intuitive from my point of view. I always forget that the catchError does not "respect" the order.It makes sense after I think about it for a minute. But it has caught me by surprise a few times. Thanks for you answer @deborahk

Answer (score 1):

You could actually send `next` and `error` callbacks to `tap` similar to `subscribe`.

```js
this.web3.useKeystoreAccess(this.passwordCtrl.value).pipe(
  tap({
    next: () => this.router.navigate(['some-route2']),
    error: () => this.router.navigate(['some-route'])
  })
).subscribe();
```

Speaking of which I'm not sure why you'd want to use the operators when the subscription is right next to it. It isn't a good idea to use the operators for the sake of using operators. For eg. `catchError` *must* return an observable but you weren't returning one because the `catchError` is redundant here.

```js
this.web3.useKeystoreAccess(this.passwordCtrl.value).subscribe({
  next: () => this.router.navigate(['some-route2']),
  error: () => this.router.navigate(['some-route'])
});
```